# How do you start training a dog for treibball?

Tags: dogs, training

I have figured out training my dog to hit the ball with the nose and a closed mouth but I'm not sure on the next step to take. Do I start with multiple balls now or should I teach getting the ball in the goal first? Or maybe training to go around and hit the ball from the other side first?

Comment: Are there any dog clubs nearby that offer classes? I know that it's a newer sport but it doesn't hurt to ask. If enough people show interest, they may start offering them.